# Get facebook user profile data, android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have integrated facebook login in my app. It works fine and in the callback method I get

This is my code

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .build();
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("basic_info","user_friends","email");
 loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
            Log.e("res",""+loginResult.getAccessToken());
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,""+loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
        }
    });
}
```

When I print the access token I get

```
{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[user_friends, contact_email, email, public_profile, basic_info]}
```

I was looking for on how to get the user's data from [FB PROFILE DATA](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user)

The method

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
    accessToken,
    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(
               JSONObject object,
               GraphResponse response) {
            // Application code
        }
    });
  Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
  parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link");
  request.setParameters(parameters);
  request.executeAsync();
```

But it asks for a seesion. From where do I get the session?

Comment: what are all datas you are trying to get?

Comment: What is the error that you get? The AccessToken is a replacement for the Session in SDK v4.

Answer (score 1):

You can use available info, after the login, using Profile class.

```
Profile.getCurrentProfile() //get current instance of logged profile
Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId() //get current id
Profile.getCurrentProfile().getName() //get current user name
```

More about it, in [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Profile/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete code with status call back and session handling..

```
  public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {
  private LoginButton facebookButton;
  private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
   //use this 
  private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
  @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try {

        // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
        // session is not null, the session state change notification
        // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
            if (pDialog != null) {
                onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
            }
        }

        uiHelper.onResume();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(Constants.TAG_EXCEPTION, e.toString());
    }
}
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

public void showLoggedInUserInfo(final Session session) {

    // Make an API call to get user data and define a
    // new callback to handle the response.
    Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session,
            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    // If the response is successful
                    if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            fbFirstName = user.getFirstName();
                            fbLastName = user.getLastName();
                            fbEmail = user.asMap().get("email").toString();

                        }
                    }

                }
 private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
        Exception exception) {

    if (state.isOpened()) {
        showLoggedInUserInfo(session);

    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        // Logged out
    }
}

            });

    request.executeAsync();
}
```

Comment: Yes the permissions are there